# Adobe Illustrator variables and scripting - Is it possible?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I've new to Illustrator so I'm not even sure if this is possible. I know there are variables and such, but can the following be done?

I have an AI doc that has a map of a state with all of it's corresponding counties. I want to be able to use a file, or DB, or something to have a list of what counties are valid.... then shade in those counties on my map.

Can those also be done for points on the map? Like maybe put a pin on it if the file/DB/etc. has certain coordinates?

TIA!

Comment: Look like a doable task if I understand it correctly. You can add a name to any object (path item) in Illustrator document. And then you can select any named object by its name and change its properties with a script. If your 'DB' will contain these names a script can use them to change corresponding items on the page. But you need to create the map with named areas. I think it will be mostly a manual part of the work.

Comment: Downvoted because there is no feedback from OP

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you have some item with name 'country2' you can select it this way:

```
app.activeDocument.pathItems['country2'].selected = true;
```

[image]

And then you can change the item as you wish.

Actually you don't even need to select anything. You can change a fill color of the items about this way:

```
// make a color
var green = new CMYKColor();
green.cyan    = 20;
green.magenta = 0;
green.yellow  = 20;
green.black   = 0;

// pick an item by the name
var item = app.activeDocument.pathItems['country2'];

// assign the color to the fillColor property of the item
item.fillColor = green;
```

[image]

So all you need is to add the names to the items in Illusrtator and then you will able to change them with a script if you have a list of the names in your 'DB'.

Something like this:

```
// colors
var green = new CMYKColor();
    green.cyan    = 20;
    green.magenta = 0;
    green.yellow  = 20;
    green.black   = 0;

var blue = new CMYKColor();
    blue.cyan    = 40;
    blue.magenta = 0;
    blue.yellow  = 0;
    blue.black   = 0;

// db
var db = {
    'Country 1': green,
    'Country 2': blue,
};

// loop trough the db
for (var country in db) {
    app.activeDocument.pathItems[country].fillColor = db[country];
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Yuri, sorry for the late reply.  The project got put on hold and I got put on another one.  However, it's back on now.  Thank you for the example.  Using this I was able to get a script partially working.  I read from a TXT file and I'm able to shade in the county.  The issue is that the document I was given has a bunch of TextFrames (labelled correctly) and a bunch of PathItems (all labeled <Path>).  On the map, the TextFrame is on top of the PathItem, so now I'm trying to see if i can find the right <Path> item for each TextFrame.  Worst case is I relabel all the <Path>items.